# Wordpress - открыть ссылки на pdf файлы в PDF Reader (pdf.js)

Tags: wordpress

Есть страницы на которых присутствуют ссылки на *.pdf файлы. Как перехватить клик на эту ссылку и открыть ее (файл) в pdf viewer?

Answer (score 0):

Вроде как-то так, должно работать.

Запускаете функцию при нажатии на кнопку или ссылку.. передаете url и открываете файл

```
function pdf_open(dataurl) {
  PDFView.open(dataurl, 0);
}
```